# Excel action from drop down menu

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am new to Excel and I need help with creating a Budget sheet in excel.

I have a section of my spreadsheet dedicated toward recording purchases over the month. In order they have the columns Date, Expenses, Amount, and Category. My category column has a drop down menu that allows me to select one of my defined categories for monthly spending.

What I am wanting to do is to have an action that automatically adds the amount in the adjacent row to a monthly total for that category, which is also on the same sheet. How would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending what column you are trying to sum, you can do it like this:

```
=sumif(D1:D20, "CategoryName", C1:C20)
```

Of course replace the cell ranges and CategoryName with your values.

The first range is the category column, the last range is the column from which you want to add the numbers.

Comment: That worked exactly as I was looking to do. Thanks a bunch!